# Smallest Euclidean norm after matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, singular-values

If you multiply a vector $x$ with a matrix $A$, where $x$ has unit Euclidean norm, is there any direction in which $x$ can point, which results in a smaller resulting magnitude than the smallest eigenvalue of $A$?

Meaning is the best choice for $x$ to minimize $\|Ax\|_2$ the eigenvector with the smallest eigenvalue?

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 6 & 2 & 6\\ 1 & 7 & 8 & 7\\ 1 & 6 & 5 & 9\\ 3 & 4 & 6 & 5 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: have you tried working out examples of this on your own for simple $2\times 2$ cases?  In particular $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & c \\ 0&1 \end{bmatrix}$ where $c$ is an arbitrary real number?

Comment: Non-symmetric matrix with only real entries. I attached it to the post. Is it positive semi definit? That might be the reason why we can use SVD, right?

Comment: You may want to take a look at Boyd & Lall's [slides](http://ee263.stanford.edu/lectures/svd.pdf) on SVD.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo It's the end in my answer...

Answer (score 1):

We can formulate your issue as:

Minimize $\|Ax\|$ under the constraint $\|x\|=1$

than can be re-phrased in the following equivalent way (because it is the Euclidean norm)

Minimize $\|Ax\|^2=(Ax)^T(Ax)=(x^TA^T)(Ax)=x^T(A^TA)x$ under the constraint $\|x\|=1$

As a consequence, it is the eigenvectors of $B:=A^TA$ that must be considered.

(have you heard about SVD and singular vectors and singular values ?)

Comment: Thank you, that looks excellent! Yes I heard of them, but now I have a way better understanding thanks to your post!

Comment: So if A would be an orthogonal matrix, which it isn't in my case (is it?), it would come down to minimizing the magnitude of x. Quite logic, if you think about it.